# How could I add a value from text that could be across multiple sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a calendar that I put people down for time off. This calendar has a sheet for each month where I put something like John-V. What I want to do is get a count for each John-V across every sheet in the workbook and multiply it by 8 and subtract the total hours from a column that has the available time off balance. For easy math purpose John gets 80hrs of vacation takes off 9 days across the year for every time John-V shows up across any sheet time balance should show 8hrs left.

Comment: It's not known what your sheets look like or what they're named, but maybe something like this:
`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({”Jan”;”Feb”;”Mar”}&”!$A$1:$Z$50”),”John-V”))*8`

Comment: Not sure how your worksheets data layout looks like perhaps you could try something like this which is not a volatile function and hence wont recalculate each time there is a change in any open workbook, therefore try: `=SUM(N(TOCOL(Jan:Mar!A1:ZZ100)="John-V"))*8`

Comment: Hi, This video about spearing formulas might give you some guidance. Similar to what Mayukh suggested above.h ttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV7GKFnS788